# Not all annotations are shown on top of bar, google charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am making charts using Google charts, but when I put in some data, the data isn't always shown.

Is it possible to say when the data doesn't fit the bar that it should be shown on top like the first one?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
                   { calc: "stringify",
                     sourceColumn: 1,
                     type: "string",
                     role: "annotation" },
                   2]);

chart.draw(view, options);
```

If the label is too big to fit entirely inside the bar, it's displayed outside

EDIT: Here some changed google example: https://jsfiddle.net/27zg15zh/

Comment: but then the data that is shown inside the bars will also be shown outside the bar. Is that something that can be fixed. just show the data that doesn't fit the bars, showing them above the bars.

Comment: this shouldnt happen, if you check the jsfiddle-example you see that copper is inside the bar and the rest outside.

Comment: @KimberlyGS i guess you dont have a 'bar: {groupWidth: "95%"}' parameter in your options. Again check the jsfiddle example. Or the bar is to small.